# jQuery Validation Remote option Flask

Tags: jquery, python, jquery-validate, flask

I'm trying to check in a form if the email address of the new user enters already exists.

This is my HTML:

```
$("#createform").validate({
            errorClass: "errormessage",
            validClass: "success",

        rules: {
            fname: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 2,
                string: true,
            },

            lname: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 2,
                string: true,
            },

            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true,
                remote: $.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + "/_check_mail")
            },

            password: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5,
            },

            confirmpassword: {
                equalTo: "#password"
            }
        }
```

And this is my Flask method:

```
@app.route('/_check_mail')
def check_mail():
    mail = request.args.get('email')
    check = database.check_mail(mail)
    return check
```

where the database.check_mail(mail) checks if the email is already in the database and returns True or False (in JSON).

When I first load the page and the client tries to acces the flask URL (/_check_mail) it works:

- Request URL:`http://0.0.0.0:5000/_check_mail`
- Request Method:GET Status
- Code:200 OK

But when I enter an email, i send this request to the server that gets a 404 respons:

- Request URL:`http://0.0.0.0:5000/[object%20Object]?email=arnoutaertgeerts%40gmail.com`
- Request Method:GET
- Status Code:404 NOT FOUND

So I think there is a problem sending the email along? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved! I used this for my request:

```
email: {
    required: true,
    email: true,
    remote: function( request, response ) {
        $.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + "/_check_mail", {
        email: $('#email').val()
        }, response);
}
```

Now everything works except for displaying the error message. When the email already exists I return the string with the error message (as told in the documentation) but the messages doesn't get displayed. But I clearly recieve it when looking at the incomming responses!

Comment: An answer should only contain the solution, and follow-up questions should be amended into your OP.  What documentation are you referring to?  [I only see two examples here, and neither one](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/remote#examples) is quite the same as your approach.

Comment: That is the documentation I'm referring to and I tried it the way they do it with php but It didn't work. And with the remote rule you should return the error text in your respons :)

Comment: Why not just use a standard generic error message on the `remote` rule?  Must it come from your remote script?