# object20Object Validation plugin Flask

Tags: jquery, python, jquery-validate, flask

I'm trying to use the Validation jQuery plugin with the flask framework. This is my code:

```
email: {
    required: true,
    email: true,
    remote: {
        url: $.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + "/_check_mail"),  
         }              
},
```

This request should get send to the servers that checks if the mail already exists in the database yes or no:

```
@app.route('/_check_mail')
def check_mail():
    mail = request.args.get('email')
    check = database.check_mail(mail)
    return check
```

The check variable is "True" if the mail doesn't exists and holds the string "This mail already exists" If the mail already exists.

However, when I try to send this to the server I get this error message:

- Request URL:http://0.0.0.0:5000/[object%20Object]?email=arnoutaertgeerts%40gmail.com
- Request Method:GET
- Status Code:404 NOT FOUND

Already tried some other things but nothing worked. Any ideas?

I think I would be able to make it work with a costum method but then I need to do a synchronous AJAX request...

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery Validation Remote option Flask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15419357/jquery-validation-remote-option-flask)

Comment: What are you trying to do? I literally can't tell

Comment: I added the server method for clarity! So I'm trying to check (by AJAX) if the mail address already exists and if yes the validation plugin should display the error message send by the response. I also tried your method:remote: function( request, response ) {
        $.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + "/_check_mail", {
        email: $('#email').val()
        }, response); which gets send to the server but the respons does not get displayed by the plugin http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15419357/jquery-validation-remote-option-flask

Comment: It's possible that there is a bug in the plugin regarding the message.  Can't you use a generic error message and just leave the `remote` rule accept a `true/false` response?  As per your other question, you said that was working.

Comment: It looked like it should work but the error message doesn't get displayed

Comment: really at my wit's end here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix it (now for real)

The problem was coming from the .getJSON method. This method is a short method for

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success
});
```

wich is actually already being used by the remote call of the validation plugin!

So the only thing I actually had to do was:

```
email: {
    required: true,
    email: true,
    remote: {
        url: "_check_mail",
        data: {
            email: function() {
                return $("#email").val();
                }
            }
         }
    },
```

Answer (score 2):

I doubt that you have a handler set up to handle the `[object Object]` route. ;-)

The issue seems to be that `$SCRIPT_ROOT` is actually some kind of JavaScript object - make sure that the final URL you pass to `getJSON` is a string (that points to the correct endpoint).

After you verify that you are hitting the correct endpoint you will need to make sure that you are returning valid JSON:

```
from flask import jsonify

# additional code

@app.route("/_check_mail")
def check_mail():
    # ... snip ...
    return jsonify(valid=check)
```

Comment: So I'm passing an object to my getJSON method instead of a string? How could I make sure that I pass a string?

Comment: Also, If I use this method: remote: function( request, response ) {
      $.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + "/_check_mail", {
       email: $('#email').val()
       }, response); The request does get to the server and I recieve a response but it just doesn't get displayed. Even if I return just false I can submit the form so this tells me the remote rule doesn't really receive the response but the client does.

Answer (score 1):

$SCRIPT_ROOT might be undefined. you have to explicitly define it yourself.

[from flask docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/jquery/#where-is-my-site) :

```
<script type=text/javascript>
  $SCRIPT_ROOT = {{ request.script_root|tojson|safe }};
</script>
```

edit :

your code is mysterious. $.getJSON is a shortcut for $.ajax to do only GET request and receive a json response. $.getJSON returns javascript object, not a string. how actually do you send your request to `check_mail`?

sample code would be:

```
$.ajax({
  type : 'GET',
  data : { email : /* argument to be supplied into `mail` var of flask's `check_email` view */ },
  url : $SCRIPT_ROOT + '/_check_email',
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `messages` option instead of trying to read it back from your remote response.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#myform').validate({
        rules: {
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true,
                remote: $.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + "/_check_mail") // make sure it just returns true or false
            }
        },
        messages:{
            email: {
                remote: "custom error message"
            }
        }           
    });

});
```

Comment: I tried this too but I think it can't work by design. Otherwise you won't be able to add two different remote rules to a field with different error messages. And even if I return false I still get the [object Object] request